# Convert a collection of 2D images into a 3D one

Tags: java, c++, 3d, vtk

I'm trying to convert a collection of 2D images (tiff file) into a 3D one with java and vtk, my problem is that my result shows the left side of the image twice. I don't know what happen with the right side.

This is my code (java):

```
public class Mytest extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private vtkPanel renWin;
    private JButton exitButton;

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Load VTK library and print which library was not properly loaded
    static {
        if (!vtkNativeLibrary.LoadAllNativeLibraries()) {
            for (vtkNativeLibrary lib : vtkNativeLibrary.values()) {
                if (!lib.IsLoaded()) {
                    System.out.println(lib.GetLibraryName() + " not loaded");
                }
            }
        }
        vtkNativeLibrary.DisableOutputWindow(null);
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    public Mytest() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        // build VTK Pipeline

        vtkTIFFReader reader = new vtkTIFFReader();
        reader.SetFileName("D:\\skeletonMasks.tiff");
        reader.Update();

        vtkContourFilter contours = new vtkContourFilter();
        contours.SetInput(reader.GetOutput());
        contours.GenerateValues(2, 0, 1);

        vtkPolyDataMapper coneMapper = new vtkPolyDataMapper();
        coneMapper.SetInputConnection(contours.GetOutputPort());

        vtkActor coneActor = new vtkActor();
        coneActor.SetMapper(coneMapper);

        renWin = new vtkPanel();
        renWin.GetRenderer().AddActor(coneActor);

        renWin.GetRenderer().GetActiveCamera().SetPosition(0, 1200, 1200);

        // Add Java UI components
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);

        add(renWin, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(exitButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    /** An ActionListener that listens to the button. */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(exitButton)) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mytest");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setSize(600, 600);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new Mytest(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The render 3D image is:

[image]

I don't know if the problem is in the vtkTIFFReader that doesn't read the image correctly or is in the vtkContourFilter that cut off part of the image.

I'm using jdk 1.6 and vtk 5.8.

You can get the tiff image here: http://froggy.lbl.gov/images/whole.frog/data/masks/tiff/. Please, I need help, I'm not an expert in vtk.

Comment: So, why the C++ tag?  You code is not valid C++.  You make no mention of C++ in your question.

Comment: It´s because vtk is a c++ library. I'm using a java wrapper. Also, someone who has used vtk with C++ could help me.